# Finding a line in a text file via an integer

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make some code that will generate a random number and then check numbers on each line in a text file to see if has already been generated. I have everything but code that will check for the number generated in the text file. Any ideas?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
    Dim Rlo As New IO.StreamReader("C:\Users\Somebody\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\RobloxRecruitV1\RobloxRecruitV1\bin\Debug\" & TheFileName.Text & ".txt")

    Dim firstLine As String
    'read first line
    firstLine = Rlo.ReadLine()
    'read secondline
    TheText.Text = Rlo.ReadLine()

    rndnumber = New Random
    number = rndnumber.Next(firstLine, TheText.Text)
    TextBox1.Text = number.ToString
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you the exact code (It's been a long time since I did anything in VB6...)

but....

I can tell you that using a stream reader is the wrong approach.

A stream reader is exactly what it's name suggests.  A constant stream of data, it starts and then stops when it reaches an end.

Now while it's true that you can to a small extent seek back and forth in a stream, that's not really what you need in this case.

What you need is to load all the lines of your file into an in memory array or some kind of hash table, then your task simply becomes one of looking to see if a given index exists.

If you have no choice but to use the file as is on disk (Due to size restrictions for example) then the approach you need is this:

1) Open the file
2) Set you position to the beginning
3) enter a loop reading sequential lines
4) once you have the line that corresponds to the count your looking for close the file and end
5) loop back round until no more lines left
6) close the file

opening and closing, then resetting each time is important, this is so that you KNOW EXACTLY where in the file your starting from each time, you could in theory keep the file open and just reset the position, but that in my mind could be dangerous esp if you have other processes writing to it.

If your file is not very big, then I'd opt for an in memory approach, load the file, perform operations on the in memory array of lines, then save it before exit.

Comment: no problem.  Sometimes it's not about looking for someone to provide some code, or even for syntactical solution, very often it's all about looking at the problem from a different angle, something which IMHO an awful lot of programmers (esp those new to the industry) don't do these days. :-)